# DHCP + Static IP for DHCP server on eth1?

Tags: 11.04, networking, dhcp

I'm trying to set up an intranet using DHCP.  I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and a ZyXEL GS2200-24 managed switch.  I installed dhcp3-server.

Here is my configuration for DHCP (/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf):

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  interface eth1;
  range 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.254;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
}
```

Here is setting or /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

```
INTERFACES="eth1"
```

Here is /etc/network/interfaces config for eth1:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Now, I try to start my server (`sudo /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server`) and I get this error:

No subnet delcaration for eth1 (no IPv4 addresses).  **Ignoring requests on eht1.  If this is not what you want, please write a subnet declaration in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment to which interface eth1 is attached.  **

If I assign eth1 an IP address, (`sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.2`) I can startup just fine.  I have not tried routing DHCP requests to the server yet, but it seems as everything is gravy.

Am I correct that I just need to permanently assign 192.168.1.2 to eth1, and then I can configure my managed switch to route requests for IP assignment to 192.168.1.2, my DHCP server?

If so, how can I do that?  Do I need to make a config change in /etc/network/interfaces ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface where the DHCP server is listening must have an Static IP of the same subnet you are using in your DHCP configuration.

To do so, edit your /etc/network/interface as follows: (assuming that 192.168.1.1 is your network gateway)

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

Then, edit your dhcpd.conf, change the range to **192.168.1.3 192.168.1.254** and add the following option line:

```
option routers 192.168.1.1;
```

Let me know if it helps.

Regards

Comment: What is the function of my network gateway (192.168.1.1)?  What does it do (I read about what it is, that it is used for connection sharing, but I don't know what it means in context), and are there other config changes I must make to support this?  Sorry, I'm new to networking = )  By the way, these changes worked great!

Comment: Ah - nevermind - I just realized the answer to my own question.  192.168.1.1 is the address for my switch, that's the default gateway = ).   Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Calvin! Good to know I could help :)

Comment: Oh, once you set your eth1 interface with a fixed address with the instructions i gave to you, dont forget to add a line:

nameserver 192.168.1.1

Inside the file /etc/resolv.conf, if your gateway is also your server for name resolution (DNS), to allow you to use aptitude or apt-get :)

Comment: Any idea why I cannot ping 192.168.1.2? from either local terminal or other machines on the network? http://askubuntu.com/questions/81898/cannot-ping-static-ip-on-eth1

Comment: I just added a comment there :)