# How to let two differnet subnets, which are created by a DHCP server, talk to each others?

Tags: networking, dhcpd

I have a ubuntu server with two ethernet cards, `eth0` and `eth1`, and plan to use it as a DHCP server to create two different subnets, `192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0` and `192.168.100.0/255.255.255.0`.

Q1: Is it possible "not" to set the static address for `eth0` and `eth1` individually on the file `/etc/network/interfaces` and ket the DHCP service works?

Q2: After the DHCP service works, no matter how I set up, how could I let two subnets talk to each other based on this Ubuntu server? Any other daemons should I enable?

Comment: A DHCP server can hand out addresses based on MAC addresses, but a server handing out addresses to itself sounds weird. As for talking to each other, you don't need to enable daemons, but set up routes pointing to the appropriate interface for the appropriate subnet.

Comment: You need to use `IP-Forwarding`. For IPv4 execute this command: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. This will enable it for all eth-interfaces. After that you can try to ping another machine in the different subnet.

Comment: @muru as for Q1, I tried not to set the interface as static and the dhcp server can't activate. But if I set the interface as static as https://askubuntu.com/questions/81837/dhcp-static-ip-for-dhcp-server-on-eth1, then everything is working well. I am not quite sure it means something. But according to your comments, it seems not necessary to set any parameter for the interface on /etc/network/interfaces. Could you please give me more clues?

Comment: @muru: handing out an ip to itself my sound weird but works. The interface is treated like any other interface, but makes everything (DNS and such stuff) more complicated. You can test it by flushing/deleting a netdevs IP with a configured dhcp running on that device and executing `dhclient -4 NETDEV`. You can then see a lease for that device in your dhcp.leases.

Comment: @KevInski oh, I don't doubt it works, but trust me when I say the guy succeeding you will be bemused.

Comment: @muru Yes, totally. I wouldn't do that either. Make it explicit not implicit ;-)

Comment: @muru, I try it several times. Everytime I commented the setting as `#iface enp11s0 inet static # address 192.168.100.150 # netmask 255.255.255.0 `on /etc/network/interfaces for interface. The dhcp server just doesn't work. How come? Could you please throw light on it? Did I miss anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IP-Forwarding` enables routing between the different subnets on your server, without specifying a static route. With `IP-Forwarding` enabled your server is now a `router` in a very basic way.

So this is working even if you choose to use another(third) or a different subnet for your ethernet devices and it doesn't matter how your clients will get the `IPs` (static, manual, auto(dhcp)).

For IPv4:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

For IPv6:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
```

You can even enable it for a specific device, but only for IPv6. The following command will show all netdevs + all + default(don't know what exactly this is for):

```
`ls /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf`
```

Comment: What is the different with "route add" command?

Comment: with `route add` you need to know which subnets you want to route and where you want to route it. In your case you can use `route add`, because this is a very basic and simple task. But the best practice for this purpose is to use `ip-forwarding`.

Comment: Great answer. How about Q1? Seemingly I have to set the interface with a static IP but you have different idea. In other words, I have to set `#iface enp11s0 inet static # address 192.168.100.150 # netmask 255.255.255.0` on /etc/network/interfaces to make it work.

Comment: You don't have to set a static IP for your enp11s0 but it is better to do so. You could add `iface enp11s0 inet dhcp`. This way the dhcp-server running on that interface will also give it an IP-address. Is there any disadvantage for you to use a static ip?

Comment: Thank you so much, Kev. I googled this issue and found there were two different versions, one is "Yes, you have to add", the other is "No, you don't". But the answers are out-of-date, therefore I decided to  do an experiment and found I have to add the entry on `/etc/network/interfaces`, because everytime I commented the entry, the dhcp server failed to start. Actually I am open to the issue, but there have an internal debate, I wnat to make sure.

Comment: BTW, if I don't add the entry, I can't figure out how the dhcp server assigns the subnet to the interface. Thank you again,