# Setup DHCP server on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, dhcp

I've been following [this](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-dhcp) tutorial from Ubuntu to set up a DHCP server on my machine, but I just can't get it work. When I run

```
sudo systemctl restart isc-dhcp-server.service
sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service
```

it gives me the error status `failed`, and the following output in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
systemd[1303]: gnome-launched-code.desktop-6211.scope: Succeeded.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly systemd[1]: Started ISC DHCP IPv4 server.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.1
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.4.1
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: All rights reserved.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: All rights reserved.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: Config file: /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: Database file: /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: PID file: /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: 
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: No subnet declaration for eth4 (no IPv4 addresses).
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: ** Ignoring requests on eth4.  If this is not what
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]:    to which interface eth4 is attached. **
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly sh[6757]: exiting.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: No subnet declaration for eth4 (no IPv4 addresses).
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: ** Ignoring requests on eth4.  If this is not what
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]:    to which interface eth4 is attached. **
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: 
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: 
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: 
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: 
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly dhcpd[6757]: exiting.
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 20 18:51:20 dragonfly systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 18:52:39 dragonfly PackageKit: daemon quit
Apr 20 18:52:39 dragonfly systemd[1]: packagekit.service: Succeeded.
```

I guess the relevant part of the error code is this:

```
No subnet declaration for eth4 (no IPv4 addresses).
Ignoring requests on eth4.  If this is not what
you want, please write a subnet declaration
in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
to which interface eth4 is attached.
```

Does anyone know what to do with this?
I also found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81837/dhcp-static-ip-for-dhcp-server-on-eth1) related question, but it is quite old, and I am still confused.

**Edit:**

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.1.150 192.168.1.200;
 option routers 192.168.1.254;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
 option domain-name "mydomain.example";
}
```

`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

```
INTERFACESv4="eth4"
```

Output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:2f:74:dd:bb:18 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.240/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft 4978sec preferred_lft 4978sec
    inet6 fe80::8452:bb97:94cd:6ea6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:50:79:76:23:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding your configuration files, `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` and `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` and the output of `ip addr`.

Comment: In `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` change this `INTERFACESv4="eth4"` to this `INTERFACESv4="enp4s0"` . Oh, but `enp4s0` is not on the correct sub-net. They have to be both on the same sub-net. Can `enp4s0` be moved to `192.168.1.240/24`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on **@Doug Smythies** comments I got it working.

First of all, I changed `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server` to `INTERFACESv4="enp4s0"`, since that is my wired interface, which I want to use for DHCP.

When I ran `ip addr`, it was telling me that interface `enp4s0` is on inet `192.168.0.240/24`. However, in my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` I was defining the subnet as `subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0`. Note difference in the subnet here, the `192.168.0.x` vs the `192.168.1.x` part. To make the DHCP server work, these have to be matching. So I had to move my interface to `192.168.1.x`. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Go to Network Settings.
2. Remove the current Wired setting.
3. Create a new one with the `+` icon.
4. Go to `IPv4` settings, change `IPv4 Method` to Manual, and set the `Addresses` fields to match your `dhcpd.conf` configurations.
   [Wired connection IPv4 configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etHIX.png)
5. Click to add and save the changes.
6. When you reopen the settings, you should see the correct IPv4 address you just set. [Wired connection IPv4 configuration check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ1II.png)

Or, I also could have rewritten my `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to match the subnet by changing everything to its 192.168.0.x equivalent, and leaving my interface settings untouched.

---

**So, now my correct setup is:**

Network Settings: [My correct setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1urI6.png)

`ip addr`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:42:1a:2c:9e:a1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
    inet 192.168.1.0/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute enp4s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8a50:e8aa:63c1:f6fa/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 20:1e:88:2e:cc:f0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp0s20f3
    inet 192.168.50.169/24 brd 192.168.50.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 15594sec preferred_lft 15594sec
    inet6 fe80::45f1:e127:53a0:e49c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf`

```
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
 range 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.200;
 option routers 192.168.1.254;
 option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2;
}
```

`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`

```
INTERFACESv4="enp4s0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favour and use systemd-networkd for setting up a DHCP server.

Example config file: `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Network]
DHCPServer=yes
Address=192.168.1.1/24
ConfigureWithoutCarrier=yes

[DHCPServer]
PoolOffset=100
PoolSize=100
```

More options to be found with `man systemd.network`, even NAT masquerading, port forwarding and all the other nice stuff.

To be enabled via `sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd` and to be started via `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd`. CLI-tool `networkctl` for monitoring.